# How can I set or append different base hrefs to different links with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, href

I want to reduce clutter in my web page code by setting multiple base hrefs for hyperlinks. Links with the same base hrefs also have the same CSS classes. Using JavaScript, is there a way to append base hrefs to the relative links? It's very difficult to explain, but here's an example:

```
<a class="blue" href="sad1.html">Sad 1</a>
<a class="blue" href="sad2.html">Sad 2</a>
<a class="red" href="angry1.html">Angry 1</a>
<a class="red" href="angry2.html">Angry 2</a>
```

I want to append one base href to all the links with a blue class, and a different base href for all the links with a red class. I'll actually have several more classes in the document, but I can finish the code if someone can provide a working sample. My page has hundreds of links, which I update often, so I need the html as trim as possible. I'm solid on HTML and CSS, but I'm still trying to learn JavaScript. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about, and are you comfortable with using jQuery? It's nice to be able to avoid jQuery when possible, but the code to do this would be cleanest with the use of jQuery.

Comment: @JamieButler "I'm solid on HTML and CSS, but I'm still trying to learn JavaScript" I'm pretty sure that jQuery is not an option ;)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function absolutizeHref(klass, base) {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("." + klass + "[href]");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
    var href = node.getAttribute("href");
    node.setAttribute("href", base + href);
  });
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  absolutizeHref("blue", "http://example.com/blue/");
  absolutizeHref("red", "http://example.com/red/");
});
```

```html
<a class="blue" href="sad1.html">Sad 1</a>
<a class="blue" href="sad2.html">Sad 2</a>
<a class="red" href="angry1.html">Angry 1</a>
<a class="red" href="angry2.html">Angry 2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. This gets into some script I don't understand, but it works perfectly.

Comment: Note that if you are relying on `DOMContentLoaded`, it will not on some older browsers (notably IE8). The easiest way is to remove the event listener sutff and just add `absolutizeHere(...)` script to the *end* of your document (so that every anchor you want to change is already loaded). The second easiest is to rely on a library like jQuery that provides a `ready` method. Third easiest, use `onload` (but it is slower, as it waits for images and everything to load). The hardest option is actually reinventing the hot water, implementing this in a backwards-compatible fashion correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an idea. Something like this:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].href = links[i].className + links[i].pathname;
}
```

```html
<a class="blue" href="sad1.html">Sad 1</a>
<a class="blue" href="sad2.html">Sad 2</a>
<a class="red" href="angry1.html">Angry 1</a>
<a class="red" href="angry2.html">Angry 2</a>
```

**Update** after re-reading the question and didn't notice this line at the first time so much..

> I want to append one base href to all the links with a blue class, and
>   a different base href for all the links with a red class.

To stick with the idea it is still quiet simple

```js
var links = {};

links.blue = document.querySelectorAll('a.blue');
links.blue.myPath = '/custom/blue/path';

links.red = document.querySelectorAll('a.red');
links.red.myPath = '/custom/red/path';

for (var key in links) {
  for(var i = 0; i < links[key].length; i++) {
    links[key][i].href = links[key].myPath + links[key][i].pathname;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="blue" href="sad1.html">Sad 1</a>
<a class="blue" href="sad2.html">Sad 2</a>
<a class="red" href="angry1.html">Angry 1</a>
<a class="red" href="angry2.html">Angry 2</a>
```

Comment: That gets the base href into the link, but it's still inserting the full path of the relative link. For example, here's the outcome with this code: file:///custom/blue/path/C:/Users/***/Desktop/sad1.html (I need to eliminate the C:/Users/***/Desktop/ portion that it's pulling from the relative link).

Comment: @selah you can try `links[key][i].href = '//' + links[key].myPath + links[key][i].pathname;` but I don't think it is really what you want. You should use absolute paths. If you deploy to a server at some stage there will be no `C:/Users/***/Desktop/` so do not bother with that. But there will be an absolute path. May download XAMPP or something so you can use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as absolute path on your computer, not sure about all opportunities for windows. But if you google for it you will find a million results with that.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer here has offered the core-js solution for this.

If you are happy to use jQuery, jQuery will provided the cleanest solution for you.

If you aren't comfortable with jQuery, but are open to using it, a quickstart guide can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)

Here's an example of solving this in jQuery. The elegance of this solution, is that all you need to do to expand it is add a key value pair to classToPrefixMap:

```js
var classToPrefixMap = {
    green: '/path/to/green/',
    blue: '/path/to/blue/'
};

for(var key in classToPrefixMap) {
    $('.' + key).each(function(index, anchor) {
 $(anchor).attr('href', classToPrefixMap[key] + $(anchor).attr('href'));
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="green" href="one.jpg">One</a>
<a class="green" href="two.jpg">Two</a>
<a class="blue" href="three.jpg">Three</a>
<a class="blue" href="four.jpg">Four</a>
```